# Modifying Mat attribute in class with mouse callback

Tags: c++, opencv

Going to explain using bullets to make it easy to read (hopefully):

- I'm writing a program which needs to be able to draw on top of images, using the mouse.
- The way I have organized the program is that each image is stored in it's own instance of a class. The instance includes a cv::Mat attribute where the image is saved, and a blank cv::Mat (I refer to as the canvas) where I want whatever is drawn to be saved. The canvas is the same size and type as the image cv::Mat.
- I've written a mouse callback function to draw rectangles, however I get an error (which I believe is to do with getting the stored canvas from the image).

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _dims && _dims <= CV_MAX_DIM) in setSize, file /tmp/opencv-0tcS7S/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 89
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-0tcS7S/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:89: error: (-215) 0 <= _dims && _dims <= CV_MAX_DIM in function setSize

Here is my code:

```
void draw(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* params){

ImgData* input = (ImgData*)params;  //Convert the struct passed in as void to a ImageData struct.

if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){

    printf("Left mouse button clicked.\n");
    input->ipt = Point(x,y);                        //Store the initial point, this point is saved in memory.
    printf("Original position = (%i,%i)\n",x,y);

}else if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP){

    cv::Mat temp_canvas;
    input->getCanvas().copyTo(temp_canvas);

    printf("Left mouse button released.\n");
    input->fpt = Point(x,y);                        //Final Point.

    cv::rectangle(temp_canvas, input->ipt, input->fpt, Scalar(200,0,0));
    input->setCanvas(temp_canvas);

}

}
```

The way I'm trying to do it is to copy the canvas from the object instance, draw the rectangle on this copy, then overwrite the old canvas with this modified canvas.

Any help with this or explanation as to why it is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's referring to line 89 in some file in the opencv library, "matrix.cpp", I think [this file](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Anyway can you stepthrough with a debugger and see which line of your code causes the crash?

Comment: error occurs at: input->getCanvas().copyTo(temp_canvas); i've tried writing this code in a different way to get around it but get the same error. Might need to approach the problem in a different way but I'm stumped atm.

Comment: Wild guess here, initialize `temp_canvas` properly (size, dims and so on).

Comment: I have tried that before, same issue... According to the documentation for the copyTo() function as well: 

"The method copies the matrix data to another matrix. Before copying the data, the method invokes

m.create(this->size(), this->type());
so that the destination matrix is reallocated if needed."

Thank you for the suggestion though I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, was simply that I wasn't passing the object correctly:

```
setMouseCallback("Window", draw, &images->at(imageShown));  // replaced the code: setMouseCallback("Window", draw, &images[imageShown]);
```

Silly mistake...